# spark write stream to DeltaTable performance in regards to increasing DeltaTable size

Tags: performance, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

How to optimize spark write stream to DeltaTable when DeltaTable size growths over time?

- I am writing stream to DeltaTable in Azure gen1 storage. After 48 hours my DeltaTable size is 500GB.
- I do partition DataFrame by `date`, `hour`, `minute`, `col1` where `col1` is String.
- I do repartition DataFrame before write.
- I use mode "append" for write.

My DeltaTable has

- `deltaTable.logRetentionDuration  = "interval 24 hours"`
- `deltaTable.deletedFileRetentionDuration  = "interval 24 hours"`
- `delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true`
- `delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact = true`

I do NOT run Vacuum. Should I do it? Will it not break the stream write job?

- I want to keep only 24 hours of data in DeltaTable.
- I do not need history of changes so I do not need the versioning feature of DeltaTable
- I have to use gen1
- I would like to use it almost like kafka: write it there, have retention period 24hour, read it and forget about the data > 24 hours. Although, I can not use kafka in this case. It must be gen1 and DeltaTable ideally.

How to ensure spark write time is constant with the assumption data volume, data variety, data characteristics do not change over time?

Comment: How the data is consumed?

Comment: it is consumed with spark.readStream.format("delta").load("...tablePath")

Comment: And what else? What do you with that data?

Comment: I am doing stream engineering and using DeltaTable to store aggregated metrics created from stream groupBy + aggregate over time window so in short: readStream ---> preprocess with some columns, groupBy with aggregate, HyperLogLog, postprocess with new columns created ---> writeStream.